# In workload management timeout operation is not working for select query

Tags: azure-synapse

I have configure the workload management and set the timeout operation for 60 sec

When I select the single table the timeout operation is not working.
Example:
`select * from table1`

While joining two tables the timeout operation is working
Example:
`select * from table1 table2`

Please let me know why timeout operation is not working for single table
Could you please answer my question.

Comment: can you elaborate on "not working"? Also what's your workload config? How many users do you have? Did you use same user for both selects or different ones?

Comment: I have set query timeout 60 sec in workload group but after 60 sec also query still executing when I use single table and I have configured workload group for 20 users and using different users and using select operations.  Why timeout operation is not working?  If I join two tables the timeout operation is working